# findpos work on ID but not class in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
highlightedBlock = document.getElementById("post-" + getLinkID);


console.log(findPos(highlightedBlock));
console.log(findPos($('.bar-holder')));
```

my second console.log return NAN, and I tried many different classes. Is this normal?

Comment: because there can be multiple elements of same class name that is why findPos does not work on class instead id must be unique for each element...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it is looking for a dom element reference(from the parameter sent to first call)

The jQuery method returns a jQuery wrapper object, not a dom element reference that could be the reason for the said result.

```
console.log(findPos(highlightedBlock));
console.log(findPos($('.bar-holder')[0]));
```

If you have multiple elements with the said class, then you will have to iterate through each element and then call `findPos` for each of them

```
$('.bar-holder').each(function () {
    console.log(findPos(this))
})
```

Comment: how to get last? bar-holder? $('bar-holder:last')?

Comment: @user3522897 `$('.bar-holder').last()` so `console.log(findPos($('.bar-holder').last()[0]));`

Comment: it says undefined hmm.. I inspect my DOM, there is only one bar-holder.